# Displaying the default back button of the navigation bar of a ContentPage assigned to the Xamarin.Forms Shell

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.forms.shell

I have a `ContentPage` which is assigned to the `Xamarin.Forms.Shell` class as a `ShellContent` and require the back button to be displayed in the navigation bar of the `ContentPage`.

The XAML source of the `ContentPage` in concern is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="UI_test.TestPage">

    <Shell.NavBarIsVisible>True</Shell.NavBarIsVisible>
    <Shell.BackButtonBehavior>
        <BackButtonBehavior IsEnabled="True" />
    </Shell.BackButtonBehavior>
    
    <Shell.FlyoutBehavior>Disabled</Shell.FlyoutBehavior>

    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout>
            <Label Text="Welcome to Xamarin.Forms!"
                VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" 
                HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

I found that that assigning a custom value to the attributes `TextOverride` and `IconOverride` of the `<BackButtonBehavior>` tag will display the back button, but I am looking for a way to display the platform's default back button (rather than a custom one) as the above `ContentPage` does not display as back button in its navigation bar as seen in the screenshot below.

[image: screenshot of the ContentPage in concern]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Your project seems to contain one page only, It won't appear if no navigation has been made, and it makes sense. If you do a `Shell.GotoAsync(..)` or `Shell.Navigation.PushAsync(..)` to navigate to another page it will then appears (the default native back button) allowing to go back to the previous page in the navigation stack.